# is there an R function that allows me us the summarize function on multiple variables within a data set? or get descriptive statistics

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, summary

i am trying to get the descriptive statistics from multiple variables between two groups. so far the only way i could find out how to use so is using the group by then summarize function. but it is alot of work to run on all the variables see below. is there any cleaner way of doing this

```
grouped_summary <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(mean_var1 = mean(variable1, na.rm = TRUE), 
  median_var1 = median(variable1, na.rm = TRUE), 
  sd_var1 = sd(variable1, na.rm = TRUE), 
  mean_var2 = mean(variable2, na.rm = TRUE), 
  median_var2 = median(variable2, na.rm = TRUE),
  sd_var2 = sd(variable2, na.rm = TRUE), 
  count = n())
```

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Comment: It might be easier if your data is reshaped from wide to long format, then grouped by variable name. But it's difficult to help without [seeing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As `jon spring` noted, look at the tidyverse documentation. In your case, it might look something like

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tibble(
  group = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_2", "group_2"),
  variable1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  variable2 = c(5,6,7,8)
)

my_data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), 
                   list(mean = mean, sd = sd), 
                   .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")
            )
```